# resultset.next() to take fewer records

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have a time period say 10:00 to 12:00,And I have a table `table12` with only 3 users(3 records).When I write this query

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
ResultSet rsta=st.executeQuery("Select * from details where user_type='user'");
while(rsta.next()){
<table>
<td><input type="text"  name="name<%=count%>" id="name<%=count%>" value="<%=rsta.getString("user")%>" ></input></td>
 </table>
 }
 }
```

The result I get is

```
10:00-user1;
10:30-user2;
11:00-user3;
11:30-user1;
12:00-user2;
12:30-user3;
```

The result I want is only this much

```
10:00-user1;
10:30-user2;
11:00-user3;
11:30-user1;
```

I need to get the 1st record from table12 back at 11:30.Is it possible?

Comment: `select * from table12 limit 4`

Comment: oh yeah..forgot about that.I will check it out

Comment: i have a where clause also.and i put limit after the where clause?should it be beofre?

Comment: `select * from table12 where something = interesting limit 4`

Comment: No didnt work.Its because of the for loop i guess..i get the same wrong result

Comment: Why do you have a `for` loop around the `while` loop? Shouldn't it just be only the `while(rsta.next())`? Seems like you're looping over the same record set 2 times.

Comment: could u write your suggestion in the answer..

Comment: mine is like this `for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
ResultSet rsta=st.executeQuery("Select * from details where user_type='user' LIMIT 4");
while(rsta.next()) { %>`

Answer (score 0):

`while(rsta.next())` already loops over your result set. You don't need the additional `for` loop around the `while` loop:

```
ResultSet rsta = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM details WHERE user_type='user' LIMIT 4")

while(rsta.next()){
    rsta.getString("user")
}
```

Comment: but then I just have 3 records there.user1,user2,user3.So limit will anyways give just 3 results..SO I need to loop again for the same query.

Comment: Limit will give you as many records as it finds, up to the number that you limit it to (4 in this case). If you're returning 3 results while your limit is set to 4, that means you only have 3 results in the database matching your search. Are you trying to generate more records than you actually have?

Comment: Yes I just have 3 records there,user1,user2,user3.Thats why I am trying to iterate over that the query again,so that it could again execute the same query over the same users

Comment: You need to re-phrase your question to explain exactly what you have, and what you want to do. I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish.